# How will be visual studio deployment scnerio

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2013

I consumed about deployment for my projects. For example I am developing a asp.net web api or asp.net mvc project on visual studio. I use local database and local file usernames and password for ssl. I finish the development and publis it on my local iis server and see the working application. After local iis test, I load it to server but sometimes forget the change web.config settings, connectionstrings, ssl certificate  paths and password. So the working server application that users accessed fails. How can I solve this problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is I replace the configuration in the **Web.Release.config** using **Transform**

So if for example in my **Web.config** I have the following connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\sample.mdf;Initial Catalog=sample;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In my **Web.Replace.config** I update the connectionString for production like this:

```
<connectionStrings xdt:Transform="Replace">
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="SERVER_CONNECTION" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Though keep in mind that the **Transformation** that I did in **Web.Replace.config** only applies when you **publish** your web app. You won't be able to test it **locally** by just running your application in Debug/Release mode

Answer (score 0):

You should implement Web.Config transformation. Check this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx) for more information.
Just to give an overview - by implementing Web.config transformation, your project will have different Web.Config file (For example, Web.config, Web.Live.config, Web.PreProd.Config, etc), i.e., each different file for diffrent build configurations. The main web.config should remain as it is. Its just the other config files where you will need to specify the configurations which you want to overwrite. Once done, if you publish with a particular build configuration, then the newly generated web.config (in publish folder) should have all configurations from web.config + the differences you would have specified in the transformed file for that build configuration.